# Find all numbers c that satisfy the conclusion of the Mean Value Theorum

Tags: calculus

> Find all numbers $c$ that satisfy the conclusion of the Mean Value Theorem for the following function and interval: $$f(x)=9x^3+9x-7$$ and $[0,2]$.

As far as I know I take the derivative of the function and set it equal to $0$ and $2$, but that isn't working. When I did that I got $\pm\sqrt{\frac{-1}{3}}$ or $\pm \sqrt{\frac{-7}{27}}$.

Answer (score 3):

We have that:
$$f(0) = -7$$
$$f(2) = 83$$
$$f'(x) = 27x^2 + 9$$

Then, there exists a $c in \ (0,2)$ such that:

$$f'(c) = \frac{f(2) - f(0)}{2- 0 } = \frac{83 + 7}{2} = 45$$

This means that you have to solve the following:

$$f'(c) = 45 \Rightarrow 27c^2 + 9 = 45 \Rightarrow 3c^2 - 4 = 0$$

Solutions are $c = \pm \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3} = \pm 1.1547\ldots$

Only $c = \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}$ is inside the set $(0,2)$ and hence this $c$ is what you are looking for.

Comment: How did 27c^2+9=45 change to 3c^2-4=0?

Comment: @Natalie Divide both sides by $9$

Answer (score 0):

I think your derivative should be equal to

$$\frac{f(2)-f(0)}{2-0}.$$